# How can I run a worker with dependencies in javascript and sveltekit

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker, sveltekit, zxcvbn

I am trying to use the module [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) in my project. It is fine for passwords up to around 50 chars. After it takes too long of a time to grade each password.

I'm trying to use workers to run the function and update the state in sveltekit. The code looks like this.

```js
// src/generator/+page.svelte

onMount(() => {
    const w = new Worker("src/routes/generator/worker");
    w.postMessage("password");
    w.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    };
  });
```

```js
// src/generator/worker.ts

import zxcvbn from "zxcvbn";    // throws error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at worker.ts:1:1)"

const passwordStrength = (password: string) => {
  const res = zxcvbn(password);
  postMessage(res);
};

self.onmessage = (e) => {
  passwordStrength(e.data);
};
```

I'm new to Sveltekit and javascript/typescript as a whole so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up importing the worker as such

```
// src/generator/+page.svelte

import MyWorker from "src/generator/worker?worker";


const w = new MyWorker();
w.postMessage("password");
w.onmessage = function (event) {
   console.log(event.data);
};
```

```js
// src/generator/worker.ts

import zxcvbn from "zxcvbn";

const passwordStrength = (password: string) => {
  const res = zxcvbn(password);
  postMessage(res);
};

self.onmessage = (e) => {
  passwordStrength(e.data);
};
```

Vite supports importing the worker directly. Then I could run it with no problem and it wouldn't block other javascript. A different solution I saw was to make the worker like this `new Worker("/my/path/workerfile?worker", {type: "module"})`

**DISCLAIMER**: Solution/explanation might not be 100% correct as I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You sould add an attribute `type="module"` on each `script` tag you used. Look the example below:

```
<script src="/path/to/your/amazing/script.js" type="module"></script>
```